Using solana-program-test, but stuck at initialize instruction
I'm new to Solana development, and I'm stuck with testing my initialize instruction. My initialize instruction is not complicated.
I'm getting this error.
thread 'test_initialize' panicked at /Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-program-test-1.18.17/src/lib.rs:713:17:
Program processor not available for myProgram (<program id>)

initialize instruction looks like below.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        seeds = [b"fund"],
        bump,
        space = 1024,
    )]
    pub fund: Account<'info, Fund>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[program]
pub mod myProgram {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        default_protocol_fee_rate: u16,
        whitelisted_tokens: Vec<Pubkey>,
        lst_caps: Vec<u64>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let fund = &mut ctx.accounts.fund;

        Ok((fund.initialize( // this just stores values
            ctx.accounts.admin.key(),
            default_protocol_fee_rate,
            whitelisted_tokens,
            lst_caps,
        ))?)
    }
}

And the test code is here.
use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, solana_program::instruction::Instruction, system_program};
use myProgram;
use solana_program_test::{processor, tokio, ProgramTest, ProgramTestContext};
use solana_sdk::{account::Account, signature::Keypair, signer::Signer, transaction::Transaction};

#[tokio::test]
async fn test_initialize() {
    let SetUpTest { validator, admin, fund } = SetUpTest::new();

    let mut context = validator.start_with_context().await;
    let amount: u64 = 1_000;

    let initialize_ix = Instruction {
        program_id: myProgram::ID,
        accounts: myProgram::accounts::Initialize {
            admin: admin.pubkey(),
            fund,
            system_program: system_program::ID,
        }.to_account_metas(None),
        data: myProgram::instruction::Initialize {
            default_protocol_fee_rate: 10,
            whitelisted_tokens: [
                Pubkey::new_unique(),
                Pubkey::new_unique(),
            ].to_vec(),
            lst_caps: [
                1000,
                2000
            ].to_vec(),
        }.try_to_vec().unwrap(),
    };

    let initialize_tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[initialize_ix],
        Some(&admin.pubkey()),
        &[&admin],
        context.last_blockhash,
    );

    context
        .banks_client
        .process_transaction(initialize_tx)
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

pub struct SetUpTest {
    pub validator: ProgramTest,
    pub admin: Keypair,
    pub fund: Pubkey,
}

impl SetUpTest {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut validator = ProgramTest::new("myProgram", myProgram::ID, None);

        let admin = Keypair::new();
        validator.add_account(
            admin.pubkey(),
            Account {
                lamports: 1_000_000_000,
                ..Account::default()
            },
        );

        let (fund_pda, _) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"fund"], &myProgram::ID);

        msg!("fund_pda: {}", fund_pda);

        Self {
            validator,
            admin,
            fund: fund_pda,
        }
    }
}

The error is ocurring at let mut validator = ProgramTest::new("myProgram", myProgram::ID, None); at the test code. Some other reference used processor!(process_instruction) at None argument, but at my case, I don't know what to put at there.
Edit
For more information, I've tried let mut validator = ProgramTest::new("myProgram", myProgram::ID, processor!(myProgram::entry));, but here's a compile issue occurs.
mismatched types
expected fn pointer `for<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd> fn(&'a anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey, &'b [AccountInfo<'c>], &'d _) -> Result<_, _>`
      found fn item `for<'info, 'a, 'b> fn(&'a anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey, &'info [AccountInfo<'info>], &'b _) -> Result<_, _> {entry}`


Are you calling your instruction in a mod with the #[program] macro? If not, that's what your issue is.

@Ahri Ah yes, I'm calling with #[program] macro. I missed it moving over here.

Could you update your code to include this? I'm pretty sure the problem is related to that but it's hard to tell if we don't have the code

@Ahri Yeah, I updated the initialize instruction code! Thanks

This is a known issue between anchor and solana-test. At the moment, the recommended workaround is to use cargo test-sbf instead of cargo test (more info on why this works here.) Depending on your exact project structure (e.g. if you have more than one program) you might have to set some env variables, check this answer for this.
If this doesn't work, here's a fork someone made to of solana-test to have it work with anchor: https://github.com/dankelleher/solana/commit/3c285b5574722bd8e7ec4c7f659ec769b9aba5ce

Side note: The anchor issue states:

If more people start reporting about it, we might PR to solana-program-test crate to include an anchor feature with Anchor's expected lifetimes

So if this bothers you, open an issue in anchor to discuss this.

Thanks! Now I get the different error. I'll mark this accepted and come back with new question.
